# Can I use external movie source on Ethopian Airlines 787?

Tags: planning, power, aircraft, in-flight-services, ethiopian-airlines

I just booked a flight on Ethiopian Airlines and I saw that the plane is a Boeing 787-8. (Dreamliner??)

1. I'm traveling with a child and I was wondering if it's possible to plug an external USB with my own movies for the flight?

   In general - How flexible that "media-center" is? (e.g - add my own subtitles to a movie)
2. I heard there is a generic AC power port - What does it means? Can I plug ANY power plug from any country?

Comment: The question was edited to mention Ethiopian but note that the in-flight entertainment system depends more on the airline than on the aircraft manufacturer. Leading IFE systems can be installed in both Boeing and Airbus aircrafts (and some others too) so that an airline can offer the same experience across its fleet and a given airplane type can be fitted with a completely different system by two different airlines.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the AC power port. Nowadays (especially if it's described as a generic power port) all of the major plug types are supported (US, UK, Europe to name just a few of them). An example can be seen here: [Flyertalk link](http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8332/8433171199_f47db8fccd_n.jpg)

Comment: Keep in mind many power outlets on aircraft are 110 VAC, but fortunately most modern electronics are wide range (100 to 240 VAC).

Answer (score -6):

I don't know for 787-8 or Ethiopian Airlines in particular, but I'm quite sure they won't allow you plugging in external USB drives, because of security reasons.

Comment: It could be nice to expand your answer and add some sources.

Comment: I've seen in-flight entertainment systems that allow you to connect USB drives for this purpose (see, for example [this article about Virgin's system](http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/117134-virgin-atlantic-in-flight-entertainment-review)). It's certainly not forbidden for security reasons. I don't know whether Ethiopian offers this service or not though.

Comment: @ZachLipton - If we leave Ethiopian aside - Does the dreamliner support that? - I mean, is there any dreamliner that support that?

Comment: The aircraft type is pretty much irrelevant.  Ethiopian's 787's use a Thales IFE system which can support external sources but it may not be enabled.

Comment: @Johns-305: Good point.  The IFE system isn't something that comes with the aircraft from the manufacturer, it's chosen and installed by the airline.